# Are Python's bytes objects also known as strings?

Tags: python, string

This is a section from [Dive Into Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/) regarding strings:

> In Python 3, all strings are sequences of Unicode characters. There is no such thing as a Python string encoded in utf-8, or a Python string encoded as CP-1252. “Is this string utf-8?” is an invalid question. utf-8 is a way of encoding characters as a sequence of bytes. If you want to take a string and turn it into a sequence of bytes in a particular character encoding, Python 3 can help you with that. If you want to take a sequence of bytes and turn it into a string, Python 3 can help you with that too. Bytes are not characters; bytes are bytes. Characters are an abstraction. A string is a sequence of those abstractions.

Earlier today I used the `hashlib` module and read the help text for `md5` that says:

> Return a new MD5 hash object; optionally initialized with a string.

Well, it doesn't accept a `string` - it accepts a `bytes` object.

Maybe I'm reading too much into this, but wouldn't it make more sense if the help text stated a `bytes` should be used instead? Or are people using the same name for strings and bytes?

Comment: What version of the Python docs were you looking at? 2.7 doesn't make the needed 3k distinction (obviously hehe), but the 3k docs I have does. (BTW, a fan of LOK? :))

Comment: Can't remember the exact version now, might be stackless even... 3 something. LOK rock ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2 and 3, `str` was used both for strings of characters as well as bytes. In Fact, until Python 2.6, there wasn't even a `bytes` type (and in 2.6 and 2.7, `bytes is str`).

The mentioned inconsistencies in the hashlib documentation are an artifact of this history.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the help is left over from Python2.

This is one of the bigger changes from 2 to 3

```
    Python2          Python3

    str              bytes
    unicode          str
```

Python2.6+ starts to prepare for the change by making `bytes` a synonym of `str`

You should report it to the developers (Unless it has already been fixed - I only have 3.1.2 here). I think the wording should probably be improved

Comment: Thanks, I'll see into reporting it